# text file with user and password

Tags: c++, file, text

I am having a problem with my text file. I'm trying to make a login with the text file.
When I compare the username and password, I only read the first line of the file, but if I remove the comparison I read to the end of the file.
Code:

```
bool logueo(string usulog,string conlog)
{

ifstream ArchivoL("users.txt");

string line;

while(getline(ArchivoL,line).good())
{
    istringstream ss(line);

    string usu,con;

    ss >> usu >> con;

    if(usu.compare(usulog) == 0 && con.compare(conlog) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
ArchivoL.close();
}
```

in main:

```
if(logueo(usu,con) == true)
            {
                cout << "Login Succ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Login Fail";
            }
```

Comment: Does your text file contain only one user?  If that is not the case, you need to read the info on other users inside a loop.  Right now, if the conditions do not match, you just return false and get out of loop without checking for other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `while` loop to

```
while(getline(ArchivoL,line).good())
{
    istringstream ss(line);

    string usu,con;

    ss >> usu >> con;

    if(usu.compare(usulog) == 0 && con.compare(conlog) == 0)
    {
        ArchivoL.close();
        return true;
    }
}

ArchivoL.close();
return false;
```